# Memory leak problems for column chart

Tags: memory, highcharts, memory-leaks, column-chart

I am not good at speaking English. Please understand.

I'm having a memory leak problem when using the stack column chart.

We update the data using setCategories, setData on a stack column chart every 2 seconds.

But, the memory usage continues to increase and the browser will be forcibly terminated.

The only thing that program does is call setCategories, setData. Is there anything I need to do to clean up the memory?

The test environment is os: windows7, windows10, browser: lastest version chrome 57.0.2987.133

you can see that you keep increasing after 1, 3, 5, 7, 10, 15, and 20 minutes.

Memory usage increases with time, so you can check it immediately.

You can check memory usage in the task window by running [shift + esc] shortcut in Chrome.

Send the sample code as an attachment. Thank you.

JQuery and Highcharts(5.0.10) use the latest version.

```
<script>

var dy = {
    instanceAlias : {}
};

var CATEGORIES = ["a1","a2","a3","a4","a5","a6","a7","a8","a9","a10","a11","a12","a13","a14","a15","a16","a17","a18","a19","a20"];

var THEME = "";
var HEIGHT = "290";

var highchartConfig = {
    column : {
        chart: {
            renderTo: null,
            type: 'column'
        },
        xAxis: {
            gridLineWidth: 1,               
            tickLength: 4,
            categories : null,
            labels : {
                rotation: 0,
                formatter : function(d){
                    return dy.instanceAlias[this.value] || this.value;
                }
            }
        },
        yAxis: {
            min : 0,
            max : 5,
            lineWidth: 1,
            tickLength: 4, // Same value as offset
            tickPosition: "outside",    
            tickWidth: 1,
            tickAmount: 3,
            tickInterval : 25,
            title: {
               style : {
                   display: 'none'
               }
            },
            stackLabels: {
                style : {
                    "fontWeight": "normal",
                    color : (THEME == "dark") ? "#b0b0b3" : "#000"
                }       
            }
        },
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                borderRadius: 6,
                borderWidth: 0,
                marker :{
                    enabled :true,
                    symbol : "circle",
                    radius : 4

                }
            }
        },
        series: null
    }
};


var stack1Config = $.extend(true,{},highchartConfig.column,{
    colors : ["#009651","#ff9800","#ff1100","#009651"], //stack colors 
    chart: {
        animation: false,           
        renderTo: "stack1",
        height : HEIGHT
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories : CATEGORIES
    },
    title: {
        style: {
            display: 'none'
        }
    },
    subtitle: {
        style: {
            display: 'none'
        }
    },
    legend : false,
    tooltip : false,
    yAxis: {
        max : null,
        tickInterval : null,
        tickLength : null,
        stackLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            useHTML : false,
            style : {
                "fontWeight": "normal",
                color : (THEME == "dark") ? "#b0b0b3" : "#000"
            }
        }
    },
    plotOptions: {                  
        column: {
            stacking: 'normal',
        },
        series: {
            animation: false,
            stickyTracking: false,
            enableMouseTracking: false,
            lineWidth: 0,     
            marker: {
                enabled : true,
                symbol : "circle",
                radius : 4
            },      
        }        
    },
    series : (function(){
        var series = new Array();
        var stack =  [           
                {id : "normal",  alias : "normal"},
                {id : "warning", alias : "warning"},
                {id : "danger",  alias : "danger"}
            ];

        for (var i = 0; i < stack.length; i++) {

            //stack column 브러시 추가.
            series.push({
                name : stack[i].alias || stack[i].id,
                id : stack[i].id,
                lineWidth: 1,
                data : (function(categories){

                        var data = [];
                        for (var i = 0; i < categories.length; i++) {
                            data.push(0);
                        }               
                        return data;                
                })(CATEGORIES)
            }); 
        }

        //circle 
        series.push({
            type : "scatter",
            name : "scatter",
            id : "scatter",
            marker: {
                 fillColor: '#FFFFFF',
                 lineWidth: 1,
                 lineColor: null 
            },
            data : (function(b){

                var data = [];
                for (var i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
                    data.push(0);
                }               
                return data;                
            })(CATEGORIES)
        });     

        console.log(series)

        return series;
    })()
});


var stack2Config = $.extend(true,{},highchartConfig.column,{
    colors :["#009651"],
    chart: {
        animation: false,
        renderTo: "stack2",
        height : HEIGHT
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories : CATEGORIES
    },
    title: {
        style: {
            display: 'none'
        }
    },
    subtitle: {
        style: {
            display: 'none'
        }
    },
    legend : false,
    tooltip : false,
    yAxis: {
        max : null,
        tickInterval : null,
        tickLength : null,
        stackLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            useHTML : false,
            style : {
                "fontWeight": "normal",
                color : (THEME == "dark") ? "#b0b0b3" : "#000"
            }
        }
    },
    plotOptions: {
        animation: false,
        stickyTracking: false,
        enableMouseTracking: false,
        lineWidth: 0,     
        marker : {
            enabled : false
        },              
        column : {
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                useHTML: true,
                x : 0,
                y : 0,
                style : {
                    "fontWeight": "normal"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    series : (function(){
        var series = new Array();
        var stack =  [           
                {id : "cpu",  alias : "CPU"}
            ];

        for (var i = 0; i < stack.length; i++) {

            //stack column 브러시 추가.
            series.push({
                name : stack[i].alias || stack[i].id,
                id : stack[i].id,
                lineWidth: 1,
                data : (function(categories){

                        var data = [];
                        for (var i = 0; i < categories.length; i++) {
                            data.push(0);
                        }               
                        return data;                
                })(CATEGORIES)
            }); 
        }

        //circle 
        series.push({
            type : "scatter",
            name : "scatter",
            id : "scatter",
            marker: {
                 fillColor: '#FFFFFF',
                 lineWidth: 1,
                 lineColor: null 
            },
            data : (function(b){

                var data = [];
                for (var i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
                    data.push(0);
                }               
                return data;                
            })(CATEGORIES)
        });     

        console.log(series)

        return series;
    })()
});

var stack1 = Highcharts.chart(stack1Config);
var stack2 = Highcharts.chart(stack2Config);




    var alarmTimeoutId = null;

    var alarmTimeout = function(){

        return setTimeout(function(){
            var ACT_COLUMN = {
                normal  : [],
                warning : [],
                danger  : [],
                scatter : [] // success,warning,danger total value
            };
            var length = 20;

            for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {  

                var normalCnt  = Math.round(Math.random()*100);
                var warningCnt = Math.round(Math.random()*100);
                var dangerCnt  = Math.round(Math.random()*100);

                ACT_COLUMN.scatter.push({ y: normalCnt+warningCnt+dangerCnt });
                ACT_COLUMN.normal.push(normalCnt);
                ACT_COLUMN.warning.push(warningCnt);
                ACT_COLUMN.danger.push(dangerCnt);  

            }               

            for (var key in ACT_COLUMN) {
                stack1.get(key).setData(ACT_COLUMN[key],false,false);   
            }

            stack1.xAxis[0].setCategories(CATEGORIES);

            ACT_COLUMN.scatter = null;
            ACT_COLUMN.normal = null;
            ACT_COLUMN.warning = null;
            ACT_COLUMN.danger = null;

            ACT_COLUMN = null;

            var cpuData = [];

            for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {

                var cpu = Math.round(Math.random()*100);
                var color = "#009651";

                if(cpu <= 50){
                    color = "#009651";
                }else if(cpu <= 80){
                    color = "#ff9800";
                }else{
                    color = "#ff1100";
                }

                cpuData.push({y : cpu, color : color });
            }

            var series = stack2.series;
            var seriesLength = series.length;

            for (var i = 0; i < seriesLength; i++) {
                series[i].setData(cpuData,false,false); 
            }           

            stack2.xAxis[0].setCategories(CATEGORIES);
            clearTimeout(alarmTimeoutId);
            alarmTimeoutId = alarmTimeout();

        }, 2000);           
    }

    alarmTimeout();


</script>
```

Comment: My think that the 12327 line on highcharts.src.js  seems to be a problem.

if (isDirtyBox || hasStackedSeries) {
           axis.redraw();
}

I've erased and tested that code, but I have not seen any continues increase in memory usage.

Please reply fast promptly. Thank you

Comment: It seems that this is a problem with Chrome 57. Fortunately enough, Chrome has been released in version 58 that is the issue free. Please test that version of Chrome to verify that the problem is now resolved.